# How to evaluate this limes?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$a_0 = 0$

$a_n = \sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}$

$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} 2^n \sqrt{2-a_{n-1}} =\ ?$$

I don't even know where to start.

Comment: First you can try build a closed form for the recurrence, maybe dont really needed but it can simplify the problem. You can see that the recurrence is a kind of $\sqrt {2+\sqrt {2+...}}$, you must see if this recurrence is 2, in any other case the limit is infinity.

Comment: As $n$ goes to infinity, if it converges, $a_n$=$a_n-1$=L solving for L we get L=2. So I would suggest multiplying the top and bottom of this limit by $\sqrt{2+a_n-1}$ and using what you know about L.

Comment: First you could prove that $(a_n)$ is increasing and bounded by 2, so it must converge to some limit $\leq 2$. Then you could see that this limit can only be 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**: First you can prove by induction that $0 \leq a_n < 2$. Thus you can put $a_n = 2\cos (t_n), 0 < t_n < \dfrac{\pi}{2}$. Thus: $2\cos(t_n) = \sqrt{2+2\cos(t_{n-1})} = 2\cos\left(\frac{t_{n-1}}{2}\right) \to t_n = \dfrac{t_{n-1}}{2}$, and $\sqrt{2-a_{n-1}} = \sqrt{2-(a_n^2-2)} = \sqrt{4-a_n^2}= 2\sin(t_n)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Great thanks, I get $\pi$ is this correct? How did you think of this substitution?

Comment: $\pi$ is the correct answer. Trick is if you have for example $ 0 < a < 2 \to 0 < \dfrac{a}{2} < 1 \to \dfrac{a}{2} = \cos \theta$ is a fine substitution.